# Is it possible to detect if an ACTION_SEND Intent suceeded?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a simple Android app with code like this (from the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

But I can't find a way to detect of the email was successfully sent (or the user cancels out).  Is there a way to read an intent response?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to read an intent response?

Not from an arbitrary activity for an arbitrary action.

The documentation for `Intent` actions will tell you if there is expected output or not. So, for example, [`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is documented to have output](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT). For those `Intent` actions, you use `startActivityForResult()`, and part of the output will be a "result code" to let you know generally what the result was.

However:

- Not every `Intent` action is documented to have output. Notably, [`ACTION_SEND` is not documented to have output](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND). In that case, you don't use `startActivityForResult()` (but instead use `startActivity()`). Even if you do use `startActivityForResult()`, you have no way to know if a negative outcome means that the user cancelled out or if the other activity simply is following the documentation and did not return a result.
- Some activities are buggy and fail to return results when they should.
- Your definition of a successful result and the activity's definition of a successful result may differ.

Comment: It breaks my heart to have to select this as the correct answer, considering that this is a simple and well documented ability on iOS.

Comment: I too ran into a similar situation and because of the lack of accurate return status, I couldn't perform an action. I'll search AOSP's bug tracker and see if anyone else reported this and if enough people ask, I'd hope Google could update the API.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an assured way to do it.

You could initiate the send using `startActivityForResult()` and hope that the activity which handles the Intent replies with a `RESULT_OK`. But you can't rely on it to work always.

AnD then you can check

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully Sharing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: That might be exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: This will work with approximately zero apps, as `ACTION_SEND` is not documented to return a result.